# Javascript Regex: PHP like Callback Variable

Tags: php, javascript, regex, variables, callback

In PHP I can get back the results from subpaterns like this:

```
preg_replace("/(a-z)/im", "$1", $string);
```

But is this possible in javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost exactly the same way:

```
"foo".replace(/f(o*)/, "found: $1");
```

gives "found: oo".

Comment: hmm, cool thanks, I wrote my script in the same way too but I wasn't sure if it works :)

Comment: +1 Yes. And the only real difference is that to retrieve the entire match, PHP uses: `$0` and JavaScript uses: `$&`.

Comment: The other ones are $` (dollarsign-backtick) == text to the left of the matched substring, and $' (dollarsign-apostrophe) == text to the right of the matched substring.